# Force date to read Day/Month/Year

Tags: date

How to I get the GNU `date` command to interpret dates in the format 'dd/mm/yyyy', for example:

What I get:

```
$ date  -d '09/07/2016'
Wed, Sep  7, 2016 12:00:00 AM
```

What I want:

```
$ date  -d '09/07/2016'
Sat, Jul  9, 2016 12:00:00 AM
```

I've tried setting `LC_ALL` but to no avail.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14322614/bash-date-not-recognising-uk-format-dd-mm-yyyy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that `date -d` is a GNU extension. The syntax it expects is fixed and independent from the locale. In particular, it does *not* use [POSIX `getdate()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getdate.html) to parse the date (even though the interface GNU `date` uses used to be called `getdate()` as well).

Some builds of some versions of busybox also recognise a `-d` option, but the range of supported formats is narrower. In particular, it does not recognise `mm/dd/YYYY`. You can however pass a `-D <strptime-format>` option (thanks @BinaryZebra) to specify the format you like:

```
$ date -D %d/%m/%Y -d 01/10/2016
Sat Oct  1 00:00:00 BST 2016
```

AT&T ([ast-open](https://github.com/att/ast)) `date`, since 1995, also supports a GNU-style `-d` option. That one does use POSIX `getdate()`. So with that `date` implementation, you can use the `DATEMSK` variable to change the way dates are parsed and since 1996, you can use [the `-p` option](https://github.com/att/ast/blob/master/src/lib/libcmd/date.c#L162) to pass a `strptime`-style parsing format on the command line:

```
$ date --version
  version         date (AT&T Research) 2011-01-27
$ date -d 01/10/2016
Sun Jan 10 13:36:39 GMT 2016
$ date -d 01/10/2016 -p %d/%m/%Y
Sat Oct  1 13:36:51 BST 2016
```

AT&T `ksh93`'s `printf %T` also uses a `getdate()`-compatible API and so can also be affected by the `DATEMSK` variable, so in ksh93, you can do:

```
$ DATEMSK=/dev/stdin <<< %d/%m/%Y printf '%T\n' 01/10/2016
Sat Oct  1 13:47:06 BST 2016
```

To parse a date portably in a `zsh` script, you can used the `strftime` builtin (after loading it) with the `-r` option:

```
$ zmodload zsh/datetime
$ strftime -s REPLY -r '%d/%m/%Y' 09/07/2016
$ strftime %c $REPLY
Sat 09 Jul 2016 00:00:00 BST
```

`zsh`'s `strftime -r` uses POSIX `strptime()` to parse the string. As such, it is locale-dependant. In a French locale for instance, you can use `strftime -r %d-%b-%Y 14-juillet-2016` to parse a French date.

Some `strptime()` implementations like GNU's still accept the English month/day names when in non-English locales, but not all (Solaris 11's one doesn't for instance). Something to bear in mind when parsing an English date in the user's locale.

Recent versions of `bash` also have a ksh-style `printf '%(format)T'`, but that one has no time parsing capability.

For completeness, on BSDs, `date` accepts a `-f <strptime-format>` which you can use in combination with `-j` to reformat a date:

```
$ date -jf %d/%m/%Y 01/10/2016
Sat Oct  1 13:47:06 BST 2016
```

Answer (score 2):

Using busybox date seems like the right choice:

```
$ busybox date -uD '%d/%m/%Y' -d '09/07/2016'
Sat Jul  9 00:00:00 UTC 2016
```

That works because busybox date accepts a format (`-D`) to read the date inside `-d`.

To make the command more reliable and to build exactly the format you ask for:

```
$ LC_ALL=C busybox date -uD '%d/%m/%Y' -d '09/07/2016' +'%a, %b %d, %Y %r'
Sat, Jul 09, 2016 12:00:00 AM
```

[Busybox date command](http://linux.die.net/man/1/busybox).

Answer (score 1):

From `info date`

> For numeric months, the ISO 8601 format `YEAR-MONTH-DAY` is allowed
>      When months are written literally, the calendar date may be given as
>   any of the following:
>
> ```
>  DAY MONTH YEAR
>  DAY MONTH
>  MONTH DAY YEAR
>  DAY-MONTH-YEAR
> ```

So main rule

> All these strings specify the same calendar date:
>
> ```
>  1972-09-24     # ISO 8601.
>  72-9-24        # Assume 19xx for 69 through 99,
>                 # 20xx for 00 through 68.
>  72-09-24       # Leading zeros are ignored.
>  9/24/72        # Common U.S. writing.
>  24 September 1972
>  24 Sept 72     # September has a special abbreviation.
>  24 Sep 72      # Three-letter abbreviations always allowed.
>  Sep 24, 1972
>  24-sep-72
>  24sep72
> ```

In the case you can use literal name of the month or rebuild date string prior to feed it to `date`

1. `IFS='/' read d m y <<<09/07/2016 ; echo "$m/$d/$y"`
2. `sed -r 's|([^/]*)/([^/]*)|\2/\1|' <<<09/07/2016`
3. `tr '/' '\n' <<<09/07/2016 | tac | tr '\n' '-'`   …

Answer (score -1):

Use the format option:

```
date -d `date -d '09/07/2016' +"%d/%m/%Y"` +"%a, %b %-d, %Y 12:00:00 AM"
```

Comment: That breaks if the day is after the 12th of a month. (And is a horrible way of cheating)