# Regex to rename Folder from "dd.mm.yy" to "yy.mm.dd"?

Tags: shell, regular-expression

I want to rename all folders from "dd.mm.yy" to "yy.mm.dd". How to do that in the shell?

Comment: I recommend you go the extra step and use the standard date format `YYYY-mm-dd`

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/534033/how-to-restructure-a-date-variable-in-bash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very easy way to do it, since already folders created.

```
ls -1d */|cut -f1 -d/ |awk -F"." '{print "mv " $0 " " $3"."$2"."$1"/"}' | bash
```

Answer (score 5):

A `bash` solution renaming the directories in your current directory:

```
for f in [0-3][0-9].[01][0-9].[0-9][0-9]; do
  [ -d "$f" ] && mv -v "$f" "${f:6}.${f:3:2}.${f:0:2}"
done
```

Answer (score 3):

Your question could use a little more information, therefore I am assuming:

- by all folders you mean all folders in the current directory
- while you mention regex, you neglected to mention OS, so I'm working on the basis that your `rename` version supports them

```
rename 's/^([0-9]{2})\.([0-9]{2})\.([0-9]{2})\//$3.$2.$1/' */
```

If you don't have `rename`, or you do and it doesn't support regex, this is a more portable approach (albeit less elegant):

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d \
  | sed 's ^./  ' \
  | grep -E "^([0-9]{2}\.){2}[0-9]{2}$" \
  | while IFS=. read dd mm yy ; do mv $dd.$mm.$yy $yy.$mm.$dd ; done
```

Answer (score 2):

I recommend not using regexes, but rather resort to date tools when it comes to handling dates, e.g.

```
for dir in */; do echo mv $dir $(LC_ALL=C busybox date -uD '%d.%m.%Y' -d "$dir" "+%Y.%m.%d") ; done
```

(inspired by [Force date to read Day/Month/Year](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/296052/force-date-to-read-day-month-year).)
I included an `echo` for "preview" mode.

Answer (score 2):

This is longer than a one-liner, but it's not making any assumptions about the date:

```
$ mkdir 12.12.12 01.02.99

$ perl -MTime::Piece -Mautodie -E '
  opendir my $dh, ".";
  while (my $f = readdir $dh) {
    if (-d $f and $f =~ /^\d\d.\d\d.\d\d$/) {
      my $t = Time::Piece->strptime($f, "%d.%m.%y");
      rename $f, $t->ymd;
    }
  }
'

$ ls
1999-02-01/  2012-12-12/
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is ugly (and fails in some situations...) but...

```
reg='^(..)\.(..)\.(..)/'
for a in */ ; do
  [[ $a =~ $reg ]] && mv $a ${BASH_REMATCH[3]}.${BASH_REMATCH[2]}.${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
done
```